# Form Validation in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using form validation of CodeIgniter, it works fine but when, form validation fails, it does not display the validation errors, by using 
`<?php echo validation_errors();?>`
I am using

```
function insertProduct(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pname','ProductName','trimirequired');
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $this->addProduct();
    }
    else{
        $this->load->model('inventory/stock');
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where you're using `validation_errors()`...? You do have a typo though: `trimirequired` should be `trim|required`.

Comment: I am using 'validation_errors()' in my view, long code, can not be given here, and when I use 'trim|required', it does not work

Comment: You should be loading the view in the else{}, why are you loading the model there?

Answer (score 0):

In your view you should have something like (this example shows errors individually);

```
<?php echo form_error('p_name'); ?>
<label for="p_name">Product Name</label>
<input type="text" id="p_name" name="p_name" value="<?php echo set_value('p_name'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the method in your controller to render a view on success/failure of the form validation.

If you change your **insertProduct** method to the following, it 'should' solve your issue.

```
function insertProduct(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pname','ProductName','trimirequired');
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $this->addProduct();
        $this->load->view('{name_of_your_view}');
    } else{
        $this->load->model('inventory/stock');
        $this->load->view('{name_of_your_view}');
    }
}
```

Where 'name_of_your_view' is the view that you've placed the **validation_errors()** code in.

Answer (score 0):

This example from the CodeIgniter tutorial pages explains how to validated submitted data to display validation errors at the header of the form like you might expect:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html

The example code for the creation function looks like this:

```
public function create()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
        $this->load->view('news/create');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->news_model->set_news();
        $this->load->view('news/success');
    }
}
```

As others have said, though, you need to add a view to handle success and return them to the form to display errors on failure.

Answer (score 0):

We can change the line containing following code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pname','ProductName','trimirequired');
```

to:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pname','ProductName','trim|required');
if($this->form_validation->run($this) == false)
{
   $this->addProduct();
}
```